# Why can't I install all packages starting with `ruby-*` pattern?

Tags: apt, dependencies, ruby

I run the command to install all about ruby : `sudo apt-get install ruby-*`
.But it shows unmet dependencies / broken packages.

[See Terminal ScreenShot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BdHJ.png)

Now tell me how to install all the packages who met dependencies (satisfied).

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update –fix-missing`

Comment: This may help: [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: @OwenHines I think this is not a dupe. There are other reason when `ruby-*` may fail. Check my answer

Comment: Please consider providing text outputs instead of screenshots. It helps finding the question and improves formatting. Thanks

Comment: @Anwar I didn't report it as a dupe, I only suggested a different answer that could have solutions.

Comment: @OwenHines People close voting to that question now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you try to install using `ruby-*`, that regex will be expanded to include all packages starting with name `ruby`. But that will only succeed if all packages starting with `ruby` don't conflict each other or can stay together happily.

The problem is, some packages with name starting with `ruby` can conflict with some other packages matched by the regex. For example, when I execute that command in my system (Ubuntu 16.04), one of the conflicts was -

```
ruby-celluloid-fsm : Breaks: ruby-celluloid (< 0.17~) but 0.16.0-4 is to be installed
```

Here `ruby-celluloid-fsm` conflicting with `ruby-celluoid`. I thought one of them is older than the other and the newer one replaces older one and can't stay together. Indeed this was the case when I checked with `apt-cache depends ruby-celluloid-fsm` command. Here is the output

```
→ apt-cache depends ruby-celluloid-fsm 
ruby-celluloid-fsm
  Depends: bundler
 |Depends: ruby
  Depends: <ruby-interpreter>
    ruby2.0:i386
    ruby2.0
    ruby2.1
    ruby2.2
    jruby
    ruby1.9.1
  Depends: ruby-dotenv
  Depends: ruby-nenv
  Depends: ruby-rspec-logsplit
  Depends: ruby-timers
  Breaks: ruby-celluloid
  Replaces: ruby-celluloid
```

You can clearly see that the package conflicts with `ruby-celluoid`, indicated by the `Breaks:` and `Replaces:` line.

So, don't install anything with `*` regex pattern, it can fail dramatically. You should only install packages what you need. **Remember**, Not all packages in official repo can be installed in a system together.